# Bootstrap messes up when adding PHP tag

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a personal project of bootstrap and wanted to experiment with some PHP. I first build out my static website and now I'm adding the PHP. The first thing I wanted to get done is the registration form. Now whithout the PHP tag (  ) everything looks just fine. But as soon as I add the tags into the source code ( even without any code ) the webpage just shows the entire sourcecode in the browser.

Comment: Is your wamp/xampp server running?

Comment: Yes it is, I'm using xampp.

Comment: Could you show what PHP code you are adding?

Comment: Are your files in .html?

Comment: Just adding an opening php-tag and closing it above my Doctype, will cause it to show the sourcecode. But this is the sourcecode it shows! http://pastie.org/9142305

Comment: Sounds like you are not accessing the file through xampp but directly instead. you need to open the page via the URL. (i.e. `http://localhost/index.php`)

Comment: Oh yah, that seemed to work, thank you for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are not accessing the file through xampp but directly instead. you need to open the page via the URL. (i.e. `http://localhost/index.php`)

Comment: Concise answer to a classic mistake.